# Unable to execute header location as a result from updating mySQL - Need Assistance

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a script that works, but I need to redirect the script to a success page or fail page.  Right now, the script works but I remain stuck in the php script, which is a blank page.

Can anyone take  look at this and let me how to fix this?

```
<?PHP
session_start();
?>

<?php

$type=$_POST['type'];
$part_no=$_POST['part_no'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$count=$_POST['count'];
$min=$_POST['min'];
$max=$_POST['max'];

$db="naturan8_hero";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db , $link)
or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query(" UPDATE cartons_current SET type='$type' ,
description='$description',count='$count' , min='$min' , max='$max' WHERE 
part_no='$part_no'");

if($query) {
header('Location: success.htm');
}else{
header('Location: fail.htm');
}

?>
```

Comment: remove the `?><?php` from after `session_start()`

Comment: If there is no output from the `die()` functions, check in what encoding you did save your PHP script file (as UTF-8 with BOM causes problems for PHP)

Comment: Ok.. Now "session_start()" shows on the page. What's this?

Comment: @Erik should be like this: `<?php session_start();` and then the rest of your code

Comment: @Erik also, I see you didn't even consider the suggestions you were given [in your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798593/trying-to-update-mysql-record-via-php-form-need-help/7798649#7798649), especially about avoiding SQL injections

Comment: @Erik You can also omit the last closing `?>`

Comment: After first suspecting that there was maybe an issue with the headers, I am now fairly convinced that it is nothing we are seeing here because I went ahead and created a test database with a table that matched the structure of yours and then copied your code and tried it out and I was directed to success.html, so it worked. You are sure you are not redirected to a blank success.html?
As a last resort I am wondering if you have an auto_prepend file? You can check this with `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

the header sent by session_start are generally cookies which can be sent at the same time as a location header no problem

@DaveRandom commented, the blank space between the ?>  from each php file

the location header should also have an absolute url

```
<?PHP
session_start();

$type=$_POST['type'];
$part_no=$_POST['part_no'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$count=$_POST['count'];
$min=$_POST['min'];
$max=$_POST['max'];

$db="naturan8_hero";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db , $link)
or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query(" UPDATE cartons_current SET type='$type' ,
description='$description',count='$count' , min='$min' , max='$max' WHERE 
part_no='$part_no'");

if($query) {
    header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/success.htm');
}else{
    header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/fail.htm');
}
exit;
```

it is also good practice to exit after the header is sent, unless you are intentionally running extra code after the redirect